# OSG: Why there is texture coordinate array but not texture itself?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, openscenegraph, 3d-modelling

I am trying to get texture file name from an `osg::Geometry` I get the texture coordinates like this:

```
osg::Geometry* geom = dynamic_cast<osg::Geometry*> (drawable);
const osg::Geometry::ArrayList& texCoordArrayList = dynamic_cast<const osg::Geometry::ArrayList&>(geom->getTexCoordArrayList());
auto texCoordArrayListSize = texCoordArrayList.size();

auto sset = geom->getOrCreateStateSet();
processStateSet(sset);

for (size_t k = 0; k < texCoordArrayListSize; k++)
{
    const osg::Vec2Array* texCoordArray = dynamic_cast<const osg::Vec2Array*>(geom->getTexCoordArray(k));
    //doing sth with vertexarray, normalarray and texCoordArray
}
```

But I am not able to get texture file name in `processStateSet()` function. I take the `processStateSet` function code from OSG examples (specifically from osganalysis example). Even though there is a texture file, Sometimes it works and gets the name but sometimes not. Here is my  `processStateSet` function

```
void processStateSet(osg::StateSet* stateset)
{
    if (!stateset) return;

    for (unsigned int ti = 0; ti < stateset->getNumTextureAttributeLists(); ++ti)
    {
        osg::StateAttribute* sa = stateset->getTextureAttribute(ti, osg::StateAttribute::TEXTURE);
        osg::Texture* texture = dynamic_cast<osg::Texture*>(sa);
        if (texture)
        {
            LOG("texture! ");

            //TODO: something with this.
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < texture->getNumImages(); ++i)
            {
                auto img (texture->getImage(i));
                auto texturefname (img->getFileName());

                LOG("image ! image no: " + IntegerToStr(i) +  " file: " + texturefname);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I just realized that: if the model that I load is ".3ds", `texturefname` is exist but if model is ".flt" there is not texture name.

Is it about loading different types? But I know that they both have textures. What is the difference? I confused.

Comment: That might depend on how the plugin that loads each 3D format and/or image type behaves: some of them might not set the filename in the image they read. Take a look at the relevant plugins code

Comment: Some 3D models don't even come with texture names

Comment: @user253751  I know that but I do not know how OSG reads the texture.  have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Some 3D models don't have texture names. Your choices are to deal with it, or use model files that do. It also depends on the format. Some formats *can't* have texture names. Some Blender export scripts can't write texture names even though the format supports it. And so on.

3D model formats are *not* interchangeable - every one is different.

Comment: I opened the "flt" model file and it contains texture name, actually I am not an expert on these topics